# Vector is not a Template?

Tags: c++, vector, sfml

I am currently trying to follow a tutorial on making a simple 2D tile engine for top-down RPGs. For some reason though I get the intellisense error

`vector is not a template`

The word "vector" is underlined with red. Why does this not work? Why is it telling me that it's a template, and why does the mean the program won't work?

```
#ifndef _IMAGEMANAGER_H
#define _IMAGEMANAGER_H

#include <vector>
#include <SFML\Graphics.hpp>

class ImageManager
{
private:
    vector<sf::Texture> textureList;

public:
    ImageManager();
    ~ImageManager();

    void AddTexture(sf::Texture& texture);
    sf::Texture& GetTexture(int index);
};
#endif
```

Errors I get (no doubt some of these spawn from the error of this part above):

> - Error  1   error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before    '<'   c:\users<omitted>\dropbox\computer science\programming\visual studio
>   2012\projects\sfml-app\sfml-app\imagemanager.h    10  1   sfml-app
> - Error  2   error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++    does not support default-int    c:\users<omitted>\dropbox\computer
>   science\programming\visual studio
>   2012\projects\sfml-app\sfml-app\imagemanager.h    10  1   sfml-app
> - Error  3   error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding    ';'   c:\users<omitted>\dropbox\computer science\programming\visual studio
>   2012\projects\sfml-app\sfml-app\imagemanager.h    10  1   sfml-app
> - Error  4   error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before    '<'   c:\users<omitted>\dropbox\computer science\programming\visual studio
>   2012\projects\sfml-app\sfml-app\imagemanager.h    10  1   sfml-app
> - Error  5   error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++    does not support default-int    c:\users<omitted>\dropbox\computer
>   science\programming\visual studio
>   2012\projects\sfml-app\sfml-app\imagemanager.h    10  1   sfml-app
> - Error  6   error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding    ';'   c:\users<omitted>\dropbox\computer science\programming\visual studio
>   2012\projects\sfml-app\sfml-app\imagemanager.h    10  1   sfml-app
> - Error  7   error C2065: 'textureList' : undeclared    identifier   c:\users<omitted>\dropbox\computer science\programming\visual
>   studio 2012\projects\sfml-app\sfml-app\imagemanager.cpp   22  1   sfml-app
> - Error  8   error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before    '<'   c:\users<omitted>\dropbox\computer science\programming\visual studio
>   2012\projects\sfml-app\sfml-app\imagemanager.h    10  1   sfml-app
> - Error  9   error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++    does not support default-int    c:\users<omitted>\dropbox\computer
>   science\programming\visual studio
>   2012\projects\sfml-app\sfml-app\imagemanager.h    10  1   sfml-app
> - Error  10  error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding    ';'   c:\users<omitted>\dropbox\computer science\programming\visual studio
>   2012\projects\sfml-app\sfml-app\imagemanager.h    10  1   sfml-app
> - 11 IntelliSense: vector is not a    template   c:\Users<omitted>\Dropbox\Computer Science\Programming\Visual
>   Studio 2012\Projects\sfml-app\sfml-app\ImageManager.h 10  2   sfml-app

Comment: You should adhere to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier

Comment: `std::vector<sf::Texture>`

Comment: Names that begin with an underscore followed by a capital letter (`_IMAGEMANAGER_H`) and names that contain two consecutive underscores are reserved to the implementation. Don't use them.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

`vector` is from the `std` namespace, so you must use `std::` to specify:

```
std::vector<sf::Texture> textureList;
```

Or you can use a `using` statement:

```
using std::vector;

vector<sf::Texture> textureList;
```

Comment: Thank you. I used the first tip which solved it. Using the namespace would most likely have solved it too.

Comment: Keep in mind that using directives are not recommended in header files.

Comment: don't forget #include <vector>

Comment: I also had to do #include<vector> further in addition to above solution as I got a error std has no member vector

Comment: Building on what Ganesh said, if you arrived here anytime after 2019, you need #include<vector> and the std::vector to use a vector.

Answer (score 11):

Since I don't see any `using` statements in your code sample, I am pretty sure you need to add `std::` to your `vector` declaration, like so:

```
std::vector<sf::Texture> textureList;
```

Comment: The other guy listed more than one solution so I accepted his, though I up-voted yours too for effort! :3

Comment: @Vipar No worries, you should pick the answer that helped you the most.